# SQL query, group by vs window function

Tags: sql

Here is the question

> A department store maintains data on customers, products, and purchase records in 3 tables: CUSTOMER, PRODUCT, and PURCHASE. The store manager wants to know which product is on maximum discount for each category. Write a query to print the following fields for each category, ordered by cateogry, ascending: category, product id and discount for the product that has the maxiumum discount in the category. In the case of multiple products having same maximum discount within a category, print the product with minimum product_id.

```
<PRODUCT table schema>
product_id
product_name
category
price
discount
available
```

This query works:

```
with ranked_discount as (
    select p.category,
         p.product_id,
         p.discount,
         row_number() over (partition by category ORDER BY discount DESC, product_id ASC) as rn_disc
     FROM Product as p
) select category, product_id, discount from ranked_discount where rn_disc = 1
```

The reason why this isn't the same query:

```
select category, product_id, MAX(discount)
FROM Product
GROUP BY category, product_id
ORDER BY category ASC
```

is because it may not get the correct `product_id` right? If two rows exist with the same category and discount and it's the max, the `GROUP BY` might choose the wrong `product_id` right?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output ?

Comment: The main difference is that window function usage keeps all rows, while GROUP BY reduces the number of rows into groups.

Comment: nah the group by runs

Comment: @jarlh: The query is valid. I misread this, too. The `GROUP BY` is on category and product_id. So the difference to the other query is that it is looking for the maximum discount per product and category, and as there is just one row per product in the table, it is selecting all products and equals a mere `SELECT category, product_id, discount FROM Product ORDER BY category`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, oops. Absolutely. (I feel somewhat stupid now. Probably need another cup of coffee.)

Comment: @Jwan622 You answered on your question! The query with `GROUP BY` does not provide desired result! Look difference here: https://sqlize.online/s/cf

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` allows you to get other data from the same row, which `GROUP BY` cannot do.

Comment: What does group by do when there's a tie?